# How to move an image after zooming?

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView and a zoomControl in my code.

First I am zooming the image by increasing the scale of the image.

Then I want to traverse(move) the whole image using onTouchListener, but the problem I am facing is that the image moves in the direction opposite to that of the direction in which I drag my finger.

This is the code I am using:

```
zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override

           public void onClick(View view) {
                float x= imageView.getScaleX();
                float y= imageView.getScaleY();
                imageView.setScaleX(x+1);
                imageView.setScaleY(y+1);
            }
        });

zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {
                float x= imageView.getScaleX();
                float y= imageView.getScaleY();
                imageView.setScaleX(x-1);
                imageView.setScaleY(y-1);
            }
        });

imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override

            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int action = motionEvent.getAction();
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                switch (action) {
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                             imageView.setPivotX(x);
                             imageView.setPivotY(y);
                             break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to set the x and y values to -x and -y? Seems like you just need to do that in order to get the right direction...